# Downloading and playing audio from cache

Tags: youtube, cache

I was wondering if there was a way to download (only audio) and play a youtube video.

How does one read and download from cache using the terminal?

Comment: I'm fairly certain you can't download YouTube videos from cache through the terminal. That's what DRM is meant to prevent. There are quite a few plugins for Firefox (and some not-from-store Chrome extensions), though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use clipconverter.cc to download audio from youtube or if you want to know about terminal read this http://www.tecmint.com/useful-basic-commands-of-apt-get-and-apt-cache-for-package-management/